# How do I wrap an element's contents in another element in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have simple tag HTML

```
<ul>              
    <li>Something1</li>
    <li>Something2</li>
    <li>Something3</li>
    <li>Something4</li>
</ul>
```

How to make it like this if I use jQuery?

```
<ul>              
    <li><a href="#">Something1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Where Something 1-4 is already defined?

Comment: Please try to set a more descriptive subject of your question. The subject is your chance to attract attention in the list of unanswered questions, a good descriptive title will give you better answers.

Comment: var listItem = $("ul li"); $.each(listItem, function(i,v){ $(this).html('<a href="#">Something'+i+'</a>'); });

Comment: My code came before the wrapInner comment. His code mimics mine. :)

Comment: @AriePrasetyo, Your code practically mimics the example given for [`wrapInner`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest reading through the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/):

```
$('li').wrapInner('<a href="#"></a>');
```

Comment: I'd not come across `wrapInner()` before, thanks for the heads-up! =)

Comment: Note: When passing a selector string to the .wrapInner() function, the expected input is well formed HTML with correctly closed tags. Examples of valid input include:

`$(elem).wrapInner("<div class='test' />");`
`$(elem).wrapInner("<div class='test'></div>");`
`$(elem).wrapInner("<div class=\"test\"></div>");`

Comment: @Hupperware, I'd missed the closing tag, thanks for catching that.

Comment: @zzzzBov Figured as much. Just thought I'd post that so no one believes it's optional. Cheers!

Comment: @Hupperware, after reviewing the docs, the closing tag seems to be optional. Here's a [test to prove it](http://jsfiddle.net/u7KPR/).

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').each(function() {
        $(this).html('<a href="#">'+$(this).text()+'</a>');
    })
})
```

Comment: I wouldn't insert `$(this).text()` in the HTML string.  Would work for your sample content but not any content.  Should be `.html()`.

Answer (score 1):

Tested, and working in Chromium 17/Ubuntu 11.04:

```
$('li').each(
    function(){
        $(this.firstChild).wrap('<a href="#"></a>');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2yJDf/1/).

Comment: probably don't want the a to be a self-closing tag!

Comment: Self closing is fine, just not self closing and a closing tag.

Comment: @AlexanderCorwin I spent the better part of a minute thinking "but Chromium's not *making* a self-closing tag..? What..?" ***sigh***, typo corrected; thanks! =D

Comment: I think you should skip the '</a>' part of the string, according to jQuery docs